# CheckBox in BaseAdapter auto check

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a `ListView` with each row consisting of a `textview` and a `checkbox`.

The user is allowed to click on each `TextView`, and once he does a `DialogBox` is presented to him where he is expected to either choose `Yes` or `No`.

When he chooses No, the `CheckBox` next to the `TextView` the user clicked needs to be ticked automatically.

The problem that I am facing is that no matter which `TextBox` the user chooses, the last `CheckBox` of the list gets ticked all the time, and not the one next to the chosen `TextView`.

After debugging I noticed that this is happening because the `getView()` method of the adapter class stops on the last row, thus the last row always gets selected.  I tried setting up tags for each row so that I can than tick the `checkbox` accordingly but then neither `Checkboxes` get ticked.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

```
....

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    .....
    holder.text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) 
        {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setTitle("Materials");
            builder.setMessage("Did you require any materials to fix this error?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    String clickedError;            
                    clickedError = holder.text.getText().toString();        

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Material.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("materialList", materialList);
                    intent.putExtra("clickedError", clickedError);
                    intent.putExtra("repairID", repairID);
                    ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    //holder.chk.setChecked(true); // This ticks the last checkbox of the list.

                    if(holder.chk.getTag() == v.getTag())
                    {
                        holder.chk.setChecked(true);
                    }   
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the checkbox for the row into your on click listener:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
.....
holder.text.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(holder.chk);
}
private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    Checkbox checkbox = null;
    public MyClickListener(final Checkbox checkbox)
    {
         this.checkbox = checkbox;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Materials");
        builder.setMessage("Did you require any materials to fix this error?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                String clickedError;            
                clickedError = holder.text.getText().toString();        

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Material.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("materialList", materialList);
                intent.putExtra("clickedError", clickedError);
                intent.putExtra("repairID", repairID);
                ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                //checkbox.setChecked(true); // This ticks the last checkbox of the list.

                if(checkbox.getTag() == v.getTag())
                {
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                }   
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You might have to make sure you pass in the appropriate variables too like mContext and clickedError (from holder.text.getText()) since you are referencing those objects.

Comment: First of all I cannot compare the getTag of v to checkbox at `if(checkbox.getTag() == v.getTag())` since the life of v begins and ends only inside `getView()`.  Secondly I don't think that separating the onClickListener from the View will make any difference since the problem here is that getView() method is still highlighting the last row of the list view since when it has created it.  This is resulting in me getting the last checkbox checked all the time.  I think that is the problem anyway.

Comment: What do you mean the life of v begins and ends in getView?  V does not exist in getView at all.  It only exists in the onClickListener and is the referenced view that is clicked.  The reason why you are retrieving the last row is because the list is populated from beginning to end and the last row is the last thing in your holder.  So when the visible list is populated one at a time, the last row is the row still held in the view holder.  When you then reference the view holder, it is the last row.  Passing in the checkbox and other variables as needed holds the correct reference

Comment: I'm very sorry.  It was my mistake.  I did not want to sound arrogant at all, I just misunderstood. I tried again this morning and your example worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot for your help. +1 and marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

CheckBox extends TextView. Use CheckBox.setText(CharSequence | int) to set text into CheckBox and remove the TextView (that will not solve your check problem, of course). Regarding your problem - it's because most AdapterView's re-use Views. Store the checked item information somewhere and in getView call setChecked(checkedItems.get(pos)).

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        .....

        holder.chk.setChecked(checkedItems.get(position))

        .....

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                //holder.chk.setChecked(true); // This ticks the last checkbox of the list.

                if(holder.chk.getTag() == v.getTag())
                {
                    holder.chk.setChecked(true);
                    checkedItems.put(position, true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where checkedItems is a SparseBooleanArray

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I still get the last checkbox of my list checked.

Comment: I believe this is happening because of how the getView() works.  Since the getView() has stopped creating the last row, than that row is still selected by the method in question, thus its checkbox gets checked.